# What is the total number of distinct sums possible from tossing six, six-sided dice?

Tags: combinatorics, arithmetic

I was reading *The Ascent of Money* by Niall Ferguson, and he writes

"... he [John Law] wagered 10,000 to 1 that a friend could not throw a designated number with six dice at one throw. (He probably lost that one [gamble] too, since here are only *31 possible outcomes: the chance of throwing 21 is about one in ten*." (the italics are mine)

How does one figure out that there are only 31 *distinct* outcomes (i.e. sums)?

Not sure what tags would be fruitful. So if you guys have suggestions for tags, rather than answers please inform me.

Comment: However note that not all outcomes are equally likely.  Despite there being only 31 distinct outcomes, the chance of getting a sum of 6 (resp. 36) is low, namely one in 6^6 = 46,656.  So offering a 10,000 to 1 wager on that sum would be profitable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well the minimum is all $1$s and the maximum is all $6$s so you have $6\times 6 - 6\times 1 + 1 = 36 - 6 + 1 =31$ possibilities.

Comment: I don't think this answer is sufficient. Can you prove that all of the integers in [6,36] can be found as sums of the dice?

Comment: Of course. $6$ is just $1$s. Now pick one die and keep incrementing it by $1$ until it reaches $6$. You get $7,8,9,10,11$. Pick another die, do the same thing and you get $12,13,14,15,16$. And you can go all the way up to $36$.

Comment: Of course the probability of each of the results differs. I don't remember my prob/stat well enough but I would assume that it's pretty much a standard bell curve with minima at 6 and 36. Which would intuitively illustrate why 21 was the one picked out as most likely; it's right at the center and therefore at the top of the bell curve.

Answer (score 4):

We want to prove that any number from 6 to 36 can be tossed. suppose k=6n with n between 1 and 5. Then we can roll $6 n$'s to get it. now suppose we want $6n+c $ with c between $1$ and $5$. then we can roll $c(n+1)$'s and roll n on the rest to get the outcome.

The minimum is $1$ in all of them $(6)$ and the max is 6 in all $(36)$ so we can get 31 possibilities.